# Specifying the data context in XAML stops the data trigger from working

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a `DataTrigger` setup like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="resultTypeStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result, Path=Result.Type}" Value="Confirmation">
                <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And two controls that use it:

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource resultTypeStyle}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2">Condition</TextBlock>
    <myns:ConditionBuilderView Style="{StaticResource resultTypeStyle}" DataContext="{Binding Condition}" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

The result type is changed by a combo box.

When the result type is Confirmation then the `TextBox` disappears but the `ConditionBuilderView` stays visible **unless** I remove the `DataContext` attribute from it.

I need to set the `DataContext` attribute so that the control gets the right data.

What does setting the data context do that means the visibility property no longer works?

Comment: Does the Condition that you are binding the DataContext to implement the Result that you are binding the Trigger to?  To ask it another way, is the DataContext of the TextBlock the same as the DataContext of the ConditionBuilderView?

Comment: I see. That makes sense now. Because I've set the data context in the ConditionBuilderView, the trigger is examining that context, not the context of the parent control that the textbox is inheriting from.

Comment: Exactly.  Good answer, @MrDosu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually changing the context used for the binding in the style of the ConditionBuilderView. So your DataTrigger looks for Result.Path on the bound Condition. If its just about Visibility this should work:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource resultTypeStyle}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2">Condition</TextBlock>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource resultTypeStyle}" >
    <myns:ConditionBuilderView DataContext="{Binding Condition}"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thanks MrDosu, that quite enlightening!